# How to avoid impedance discontinuity when a pcb trace is routed in multiple layers

Tags: electromagnetism, microwave, signal-integrity, high-speed, reflection

What are the things to be take care to avoid reflections when a PCB trace is routed in multiple layers. I mean, How to achieve impedance control when trace moves from one layer to other.

Comment: It all depends on the frequency (if RF), or edge speed (if digital) of the signal.

Comment: But if you really care about impedance discontinuities when changing layers (through a via, I assume), then there are tools that will allow you to match the impedance of the via to that of your traces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vias will add a delay, this must be accounted for if length matching.

If you are using the same reference plane (like if you're on the top layer, and the next layer down is ground, and then the next layer below that is signal ) then the return current will not reroute and have an inductance penalty which could affect rise times.

This is for a 1.6GHz design. If you are switching reference planes (from ground to ground) then use stitching vias for the return current. It's recommended for diff pairs to place them about the same distance as the diff pair at least. Same thing goes for single ended pairs, they need a via nearby if switching layers and reference planes.
[image]

If you are switching from a GND plane to a power plane for the reference plane, then add stitching capacitors near the point where the plane switch occurs. It's hard to give a definite rule on distance from the via on this one because it's frequency dependent.